# How to append value from form field in a new form field

Tags: jquery, append

Here's the story.

I have a form with some form fields.

**Example:**

- name
- email
- message

What I would like to do is when I click to submit the form, get JQuery to grab the email field value and append it to the message field.

**I have the value stored here:**

```
var email = $('#email').val();
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$("#message").val ($("#message").val () + $('#email').val());
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

$("#message").val( $("#message").val() + $('#email').val() );